# How to idiomatically manage references between terraform projects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have 2 Terraform projects going to be potentially managed by different teams.

One belongs to the **platform team** and this manages the VPC area of AWS (VPC/Subnet/Security Groups).

The other belongs to a **development team** and they manage the instances for their project.

**Example**

**Platform Team Project Resource**

```
resource "aws_subnet" "my_subnet" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.my_vpc.id}"
    cidr_block = "${var.my_subnet_id}"

    tags {
    Name = "My Subnet"
    }
}
```

**Dev Team Project Reference**

```
resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "dev_subnet" {
    name = "Developer Subnet Group"
    subnet_ids = ["subnet-a32322d8", "subnet-a43564e9"] # I really want to reference ${aws_subnet.my_subnet.id} but this terraform project is not available to the developer
}
```

The subnet_ids are just the values at that point in time. I can move these to variables if I wanted to but that doesn't seem to really solve the problem because any dependent id can change at any point in time?

**Question**

So how does one properly deal with references between the projects? The development team will need the IDs from the various VPC elements, so what is the best way to reference this?

The option I see that's available is to make use of `terraform import` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on how broadly you need to share things across teams.

In the example in the question then you don't actually need to share anything and can instead have the dev team use a data source to look up the subnet ids they should deploy things into.

As an example your platform team would create subnets like so:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "private_a" {
  vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.my_vpc.id}"
  cidr_block = "${cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.my_vpc.cidr_block, 2, 1)}"
  availability_zone = "eu-west-1a"

  tags {
    Name = "${var.vpc_name}-private-a"
    Tier = "private"
    AZ   = "a"
  }
}
```

And then your dev team simply wants to deploy into private subnets so they use the [`aws_subnet_ids` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/subnet_ids.html) to find these at runtime:

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "private" {
  vpc_id = "${var.vpc_id}"
  tags {
    Tier = "private"
  }
}

resource "aws_db_subnet_group" "dev_subnet" {
  name       = "Developer Database Subnet Group"
  subnet_ids = ["${data.aws_subnet_ids.private.ids}"]
}
```

In this actual case I would have just provided the database subnet group when you created the VPC though because it's not really something you need granular control of and ultimately everyone should be putting databases in private subnets that span all the AZs you use (which should also be all of the available ones in the region really).

As to your final question, `terraform import` is for importing a resource into the state file so that things created outside of Terraform can be managed by Terraform in the future. You will need a unique resource ID for this to be importable so doesn't solve your problem and would mean that the dev team would then have control over managing the subnet resources which is probably not what you want.